# Convert List<String> to List<dynamic>

Tags: arrays, listview, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have created a list in my program as a String list as below.

```
List<String> finalcats = [];
```

Then I added used shred preferences since I want to use it in another page

```
prefs.setStringList("postcategories", finalcats);
```

Now I want to retrieve this in another page.

***`prefs.getStringList("postcategories")`*** works fine for retrieving but I want it as a List .

How can I convert the List finalcats = []; to List = [];

Comment: I am confused. Can you give a complete example which shows your problem?

Comment: @julemand101 in my application I select a list from one page and going to use it in another page. With sharedpreferences it only supports List<String> type. So I saved my data List as a  List<String>. But in the other page I want to convert that List<String> to List<dynamic> or List = [{mydata}] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getStringList` method always return `List<String>`. You can cast this using `as` keyword. For example

```
List<String> categories = prefs.getStringList("postcategories");
List<dynamic> dynamicCategories = categories as List<dynamic>;
```

Or you can loop over the list and convert each element into a `Map` like this

```
categories.map((value) => {'key': value}).toList();
```